# Aptana unable to find java

Tags: 11.04, eclipse, ide

I am getting the following errors when i am running aptana

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run AptanaStudio3. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/opt/aptanastudio3/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

.

```
300E7Z:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

My JDK path is `/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_03`

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?  The latest version of Aptana with JRE from repository works for me.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me
Install Eclipse from repository
`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`
Install the plug-in instead of the portable
It all just works.

Answer (score 1):

I had OpenJDK when i installed aptana. So i installed SunJava and this helped but still not much . Doing `aptana -vm /path/to/sunjdk` helped. But i wanted something simpler. So this is what finally helped me.

Uninstalling Aptana and restart the sytem.

Now install aptana again

Answer (score 1):

My Ubuntu 12.04 also displayed the same error. I followed the instructions from the [Thumbring blog](http://hi.baidu.com/thumbring/blog/item/2a3c621e37954c3f4034177b.html) and I could start Eclipse after that.

Run the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/java 300  
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/javac 300  
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/jar 300   
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javah javah /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/javah 300   
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javap javap /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/javap 300
```

And then, run this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is attempting to locate a JRE at the location /opt/aptanastudio3/jre/bin/java. However, there is no JRE at that location.

**Create a symlink that points Aptana to the actual location of your JRE:**

```
ln -s /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_03 /opt/aptanastudio3/jre/bin
```

This should then mean that you can locate the java executable at the path:  /opt/aptanastudio3/jre/bin/java. This assumes the directory /opt/aptanastudio3/jre/ and /opt/aptanastudio3/jre/bin exist. If they don't, you'll need to create them.

Comment: still giving the same error