# Is any one using Aptana Studio with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, development, plugins, web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsatisfied Link Error and missing .so files when starting Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125150/unsatisfied-link-error-and-missing-so-files-when-starting-eclipse)

Is any one using Aptana studio as a stand alone in ubuntu 12.04?

I have downloaded the file, and have the latest Oracle sun java installed. but when I double click the aptanastudio3 icon it tels me to search for a program to open it...

any special way i need to go about things?

Answer (score 1):

Install eclipse from repository and add the plug-in.  That approach has worked fine here.  Recently there have been lots of issues with odd Java stuff in 12.04.

Tested working in 12.04 and 12.04.1

See also: [Aptana unable to find java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108752/aptana-unable-to-find-java)
Those are the steps that have worked for me in the passed and still do.

Comment: will try this and post back here, 250mb download on slow connection

Comment: also could this be that i only have the jre of java and the kde? the download on the java website only gave the jre in the tar.gz

Comment: it runs fine with the openjdk

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, was solved by reading their getting started guide. Not exactly sure where in the article it is at but I assure you it's there.

http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/getting_started