# problem opening eclipse

Tags: eclipse, development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsatisfied Link Error and missing .so files when starting Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125150/unsatisfied-link-error-and-missing-so-files-when-starting-eclipse)

I'm having a problem loading Eclipise in 12.04. I loaded the error log and this was inside:

```
!SESSION 2012-09-03 16:52:09.742 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-09-03 16:52:11.317
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
    no swt-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /home/marcel/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
    Can't load library: /home/marcel/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

I had openJDK installed and to remove and replace with Oracle Java to install Aptana Studio.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182307/is-any-one-using-aptana-studio-with-ubuntu-12-04) explains it all.

So now reinstalled OpenJDK, this might give some insight to the problem?

Comment: I installed Eclipse (zip distribution downloaded from Eclipse site) with Oracle JDK 6 on Ubuntu 12.04. and did not have any problem. What version of openJDK do you use?

Comment: this is the openJDK7 from the software center

Comment: Any other input for this?

Comment: It may openJDk7 problem. Try once with oracle JDK 6, it might solve your problem.

Comment: i am also using open jdk 7 and it's working fine for me 12.04 64 bit. Regarding eclipse, I dl it from the eclipse site for linux; unzipping the folder and running the eclipse worked for me again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded the Eclipse studio from the eclipse site at

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/R/eclipse-jee-juno-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

The eclipse in the app store for ubuntu 12.04 is out dated and seems like the download from the site was what was needed, installed and works properly.

By going Help->install new software and adding in http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install as the "work with" source I was able to install aptana studio plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install Eclipse with Java is : sudo apt-get install eclipse-jdt.

Nice clean and simple.